# Windows 10 becomes non-responsive after a brief period

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

This has been bugging me for a few days now, and I have yet to find whats going on to make this happen and I have tried just about everything I can think of to fix it.

Basically what happens is my computer starts and runs normally until Windows stops responding. Some apps will keep running for awhile while the rest of the system does not respond to anything, but eventually the apps will stop responding themselves.

Things to note:

- Ctrl+alt+delete and other keyboard hotkeys dont work once things start to become non-responsive.
- Task manager freezes and wont restart explorer.exe
- Start/Taskbar is completely unresponsive (usually the first 'victim')
- Nothing shows high usage or high temperature in Task Manager or HWMonitor when things start becoming non-responsive.
- HDTune reports HDDs are healthy
- No error log or error popup
- Drivers are all up to date
- Malwarebytes/rkill shows no malware when I can manage a scan before it freezes again.
  -Can get frozen on the login screen if I dont login fast enough
- Cursor is still movable and can sometimes select a different frozen window to focus. Never seems to get frozen like the rest of the system

Things I have tried:

- Tried turning off every app running, still get this problem.
- Multiple restarts have done nothing
- Reset Windows 10
- Numerous other 'fixes' I have found for related problems of dubious efficacy

Reseting Windows 10 seemed to work for a little bit before this problem came back, making me think the problem might be related to a recent windows update. I have tried to remove the updates I can remove, but the problem still persists.

If anyone has dealt with anything similar or know whats the problem here, let me know! This is frustrating me to no end and im starting to pull my hair out.

Comment: Try booting and operating from a USB flash to determine if its an OS issue, and also to do a full virus (and bitcoin miner) scan.

Comment: What version of Malwarebytes are you running?  What component package are you using?  What update package are you using?  Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: last Malwarebyte updates had memory leak. update to last version/update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to update this, but it was the system drive failing that was causing the problem, even though it reported being healthy. Replacing the drive and reinstalling fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Malwarebytes, which I will expand to Malwarebytes Antimalware. I recently had a problem similar to yours, in which I could observe the active memory usage climb like a rocket, without any process attributed to the usage. In short order, the computer would lock up.

Through trial and error, killing off various processes, I was able to determine that Malwarebytes had become corrupt. A removal and re-installation failed to solve the problem. It was necessary to remove the program, run Ccleaner to purge the registry and re-install. It's been many days without a repeat.

This isn't necessarily your solution, but it's a possibility. Your timeline matches mine.

Comment: If this happened recently, Malwarebytes released a malformed protection update.  [PSA: If you're experiencing high resource usage, update Malwarebytes](https://www.neowin.net/news/psa-if-youre-experiencing-high-resource-usage-update-malwarebytes).  I would have submitted this as an answer, if the author had supplied specifics, about their installation.

Comment: I dealt with this recently too , and this freezing happened even with Malwarebytes Antimalware uninstalled. This appears fixed now though, and this freezing that I've been dealing with doesn't show any memory or disk usage spike to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the exact same problems you noted, it started today after a Windows cumulative update (Jan 31, KB4058258)

Apps will freeze one by one, taskbar and start menu will stop working, alt-tabbing between windows won't work, ctrl-alt-del won't display the regular blue screen. While using Chrome, I'll still be able to open/close tabs, but trying to access a new page will get stuck on a blank state with the status bar showing "Waiting for cache.." The mouse cursor is typically the last thing still working, with the rest of the OS completely frozen.

I end up having to do a hard-reboot, and the computer is fine again. Then 10 minutes later things start freezing again.

My CPU is a AMD Ryzen, I wonder if the recent Spectre fix could be messing up with this?

Not using Malwarebytes or any anti-virus/malware programs other than the one built-in into Windows.

Comment: Yup this sounds exactly what im dealing with, even the 'Waiting for cache' bit in chrome. So far, Reseting windows to its installation state and disabling windows updates has been the only thing that's worked so far. Not a great solution, but the update seems to be the problem...

Comment: I ended up doing a format + Windows reinstall, downloaded latest Windows updates (including the cumulative update that originally caused the problem), and haven't had the problem so far.